# PyMySQL keeps connection error

Tags: python, mysql

I've tried a bunch of thinks including trying to specify the UNIX socket to no avail, I'm not running any queries and I haven't even initialized a cursor but I keep getting this error, what gives?

Python Block:

```
connection = mysql.connect(user = "root", password = None, port = 8080, host = 'localhost', db ='Articles')
```

Error:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Adrian/Desktop/Python/webcrawl.py", line 10, in <module>
    connection = mysql.connect(user = "root", password = None, port = 8080, host = 'localhost', db ='Articles')
  File "/Users/Adrian/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/__init__.py", line 90, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Adrian/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 699, in __init__
    self.connect()
  File "/Users/Adrian/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 935, in connect
    self._get_server_information()
  File "/Users/Adrian/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1249, in _get_server_information
    packet = self._read_packet()
  File "/Users/Adrian/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 991, in _read_packet
    packet_header = self._read_bytes(4)
  File "/Users/Adrian/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1037, in _read_bytes
    CR.CR_SERVER_LOST, "Lost connection to MySQL server during query")
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')
```

Edit: I'm running XAMPP 7.2 on MacOSX with port forwarding enabled over SSH (localhost:8080 -> 80) and the opt/lampp volumes are mounted

Answer (score 0):

It's not advisable to use root without password.

In some databases you are forced to set it if you want to connect as root.

You can set any password: [dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html)

Also, 8080 might be the port of your web server, not the mySQL one, try with 3306 port which is the default one for mySQL.

You can open my.cnf file located in the /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/ directory to chech in which port is your database listening.

Also check that the mySQL daemon is running. In mac os X go to `/Applications/XAMPP/XAMPP` Control in Finder and check that Apache and MySQL are running.

If your MySQL server isn't starting, you may need to set the permissions for it using Terminal with this command:

```
chmod -R 777 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var
```

To check that your Articles database exists:

```
mysql -u root -p
USE Articles;
```

If it's not created;

```
mysql -u root -p
CREATE DATABASE Articles;
```

And connect this way:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import MySQLdb

connection = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", 
                             user="root", 
                             passwd="your pwd",
                             db="Articles")
```

Comment: Just tried your solution and I'm getting the same error unfortunately

Comment: Try with port 3306 which is the default one. 8080 is often used by web servers instead of databases.

Comment: this returns a different error `(2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 61] Connection refused)")`

Comment: Check in which port is your database listening in XAMPP/mysql/bin/my.ini file. In [mysqld] section.

Comment: If your port is 3306, the default one, either your database is not running or there is a firewall. But there should be no problem of a firewall blocking localhost, your database daemon is likely to be stopped.

Comment: Go to  `/Applications/XAMPP/XAMPP Control` in finder and check that apache and mySQL are running.

Comment: While I could not find the file you specified, the relevant details were in a file called properties.ini (in the lampp directory)

The default sql port is indeed 3306 however still no success

Comment: Read my updated answer, check the `XAMPP Control` and set some permissions to the `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var` if the mysql server is not starting.

Comment: I don't have that director on my version but I have found a file called ctlscript.sh, is that the same?

Comment: I've found: The name of the XAMPP Control is "manager-osx"  https://www.apachefriends.org/faq_osx.html

Comment: Well, but mysql is running, the port should be in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/my.cnf file. It seems they moved it.

Comment: i've search for manager-osx, and all i have is manager-linux-x64.run !

Comment: And I suppose your database Articles is created, is it? And root user has grant access to it.

Comment: https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/mysql/managing-mysql-databases-and-users-from-the-command-line

Comment: I've gotten my details from my.cnf:

Comment: `user = mysql
port=3306
socket  = /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock`

Comment: even after changing the user to `mysql` it does not work

Comment: Perfect, the port is 3306 as I expected, now try to access to it with your root user `mysql -u root -p` and check that the database is created `USE Articles;` or create it `CREATE DATABASE Articles;`

Comment: Wait a minute, set user = root in your my.cnf file and restart your mysql server from that console.

Comment: user changed to root

Comment: It's your script still failing while trying to connect as root after a restart of the mysql database from the console?

Comment: yup, unfortunately

Comment: One last thing. Shouldn't it be MySQLdb.connect() instead of mysql.connect()?
 https://pythonspot.com/mysql-with-python/ And I think the port is optional, you can remove it from the connection details.